# Many unknown modules in node_modules folder

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs. And I found that there are many unknown modules in node_modules folder after I installed three modules (express, jade, gulp) in my local project.

Unknown module examples in the node_modules:

- vary
- statuses
- send
- promise

From the tutorials I see from others, after they installed gulp, there will be only one "gulp" folder in their node_modules folder, but this is not my case. Why? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node package manager (`npm`) updated recently, as part of that update, all modules are installed in the top level `node_modules` folder. This includes modules that your dependencies need to install. In the past these modules would be nested inside another `node_modules` folder in `express` (for example).

This is why the tutorials you read say different, likely they were written before this update.

It is mentioned in the npm changelog [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#flat-flat-flat)

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is
> possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR
> dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder
> with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another
> when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.
>
> #3697 This will hopefully eliminate most cases where windows users ended up with paths that were too long for Explorer and other standard
> tools to deal with.
>
> #6912 (#4761 #4037) This also means that your installs will be deduped from the start.
>
> #5827 This deduping even extends to git deps.
>
> #6936 (#5698) Various commands are dedupe aware now. This has some implications for the behavior of other commands:
>
> npm uninstall removes any dependencies of the module that you
> specified that aren't required by any other module. Previously, it
> would only remove those that happened to be installed under it,
> resulting in left over cruft if you'd ever deduped. npm ls now shows
> you your dependency tree organized around what requires what, rather
> than where those modules are on disk.
>
> #6937 npm dedupe now flattens the tree in addition to deduping. And bundling of dependencies when packing or publishing changes too:
>
> #2442 bundledDependencies no longer requires that you specify deduped sub deps. npm can now see that a dependency is required by something
> bundled and automatically include it. To put that another way,
> bundledDependencies should ONLY include things that you included in
> dependencies, optionalDependencies or devDependencies.
>
> #5437 When bundling a dependency that's both a devDependency and the child of a regular dependency, npm bundles the child dependency. As a
> demonstration of our confidence in our own work, npm's own
> dependencies are now flattened, deduped, and bundled in the npm@3
> style. This means that npm@3 can't be packed or published by npm@2,
> which is something to be aware of if you're hacking on npm.

Comment: Thanks. Straight forward and helpful answer!